# How can i change a pandas dataframe to a binary matrix?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

df.head()

```
 Name                         Application                  time
Administrator                   Excel                        1
Reception                       Word                         1
Manager                         Internet                     1
Administrator                   Excel                        2
Reception                       Email                        5
```

I try to make a binary matrix with all different applications as column names and for every different user the time of every application used summed:

```
Name             Email   Email_time   Excel    Excel_time   Internet  Internet_time   Word    Word_time    
Administrator      0         0           1           3         0               0        0       0
Manager            0         0           0           0         1               1        0       0
Reception          1         5           0           0         0               0        1       1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) and for binary compare values for not equal by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) and convert to integer by `astype`:

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index='Name',
                    columns='Application',
                    values='time',
                    aggfunc='sum',
                    fill_value=0)

df = df2.ne(0).astype(int).join(df2.add_suffix('_time')).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
Application    Email  Email_time  Excel  Excel_time  Internet  Internet_time  \
Name                                                                           
Administrator      0           0      1           3         0              0   
Manager            0           0      0           0         1              1   
Reception          1           5      0           0         0              0   

Application    Word  Word_time  
Name                            
Administrator     0          0  
Manager           0          0  
Reception         1          1
```

Last if necessary column from index:

```
df = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

EDIT:

If possible some nagatve values and sum should be `0`, here is alternative with [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and `max`:

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Name')['Application']).max(level=0)
df2 = df.pivot_table(index='Name',
                    columns='Application',
                    values='time',
                    aggfunc='sum',
                    fill_value=0)

df = df1.join(df2.add_suffix('_time'))
print (df)
               Email  Excel  Internet  Word  Email_time  Excel_time  \
Name                                                                  
Administrator      0      1         0     0           0           3   
Reception          1      0         0     1           5           0   
Manager            0      0         1     0           0           0   

               Internet_time  Word_time  
Name                                     
Administrator              0          0  
Reception                  0          1  
Manager                    1          0
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `groupby` with `agg`

```
a = df.groupby(['Name', 'Application']).time.agg(['count', 'sum'])
c = a['count'].unstack(fill_value=0)
s = a['sum'].unstack(fill_value=0).add_suffix('_time')
c.join(s).sort_index(1)

Application    Email  Email_time  Excel  Excel_time  Internet  Internet_time  Word  Word_time
Name                                                                                         
Administrator      0           0      2           3         0              0     0          0
Manager            0           0      0           0         1              1     0          0
Reception          1           5      0           0         0              0     1          1
```